# Entity Framework save changed data as a copy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I need to change data as a copy of originally chaged model/ If ill sae it like this, would this affect original data?

```
var val = context.RecordsContent.Find(id);
val.Text = "CHANGED";
var newval = new LocalizedText { Record = val.Record, Text = val.Text, Mask = val.Mask, Type = val.Type, Rev = val.Rev + 1 };
context.RecordsContent.Add(newval);
```

Do I need to use another instance of context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not persisting the changes yet; however, after `SaveChanges` is called, it will save the new value of `val.Text` as well as the new `newVal` object.

If you don't want to persist changes made on `val` you could make a copy by creating a new object and setting all its properties, pretty much what you are already doing with `newvVal`